# Configure mapper-locations in spring-mybatis with classpath:*

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

So I want this to work

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.mybatis-factory")
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean() {
  SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
  sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
  return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

with property (among others)

```
datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-locations=classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml
```

However, it fails even though the files are there:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Looking at `setMapperLocations()` I didn't do anything wrong, they clearly want me to use `classpath*:...`:

```
/**
 * Set locations of MyBatis mapper files that are going to be merged into the {@code SqlSessionFactory} configuration
 * at runtime.
 *
 * This is an alternative to specifying "&lt;sqlmapper&gt;" entries in an MyBatis config file. This property being
 * based on Spring's resource abstraction also allows for specifying resource patterns here: e.g.
 * "classpath*:sqlmap/*-mapper.xml".
 *
 * @param mapperLocations
 *          location of MyBatis mapper files
 */
public void setMapperLocations(Resource... mapperLocations) {
  this.mapperLocations = mapperLocations;
}
```

Looking further down the code there's just this:

```
    for (Resource mapperLocation : this.mapperLocations) {
      if (mapperLocation == null) {
        continue;
      }
      try {
        XMLMapperBuilder xmlMapperBuilder = new XMLMapperBuilder(mapperLocation.getInputStream(),
            targetConfiguration, mapperLocation.toString(), targetConfiguration.getSqlFragments());
        xmlMapperBuilder.parse();
```

There is no code that would convert the `classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml` into openable resources or at least I don't see it. Or what am I missing here?

*Work around:*
What I have now and is working (note that I don't use `datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-locations` as that would again overwrite what I set):

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.mybatis-factory")
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean(
    @Value("${datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-location-pattern}") String mapperLocations) {
  SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
  sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
  sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(findMapperLocations(mapperLocations));
  return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
}

private Resource[] findMapperLocations(String resourcePaths) {
  PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
  return Stream.of(resourcePaths.split(","))
      .map(LambdaExceptionUtilities.rethrowFunction(patternResolver::getResources))
      .flatMap(Stream::of)
      .toArray(Resource[]::new);
}
```

with property

```
datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-location-pattern=classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml
```

So: what is missing here to make it work **without the work around**? How do XMLs on the classpath find the way into MyBatis? Maybe something Spring-Bootish missing?

Comment: With mybatis-spring-boot-starter, all you need to do is to specify `mybatis.mapper-locations` in `application.properties`. Read the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).

Comment: @ave I assume that using `@ConfigurationProperties` like I did would do the same thing, no? We have an application that accesses two different databases where the configurations don't match and they also shouldn't share the XMLs.

Comment: The example on this [page](https://qiita.com/KevinFQ/items/a8de808e7719315c376c#mybatis%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88) would be close to what you want (it's a Japanese page, but the code should be self-explanatory). Directly applying `@ConfigurationProperties` might be difficult because `SqlSessionFactoryBean` is a factory bean. If you need to load mapper locations from a .properties file, you would have to use some other method like `@Value`.

Comment: @ave That page is describing what I'm doing with the work around. The only difference is that their values are hard-coded, which is bad. Reading of properties is working fine for me. It's just not converting the mapper locations to proper resources automatically.

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstanding. It seems like a spring boot issue and there is an open [ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15835).

Comment: @ave Ah, thanks! My google didn't find that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently. I believe this is what what you're looking for:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.mybatis-factory")
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean(
    @Value("${datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-location-pattern}") String mapperLocations) {
  SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
  sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
  sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(
      new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml")
  );
  return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Basically what you need is this line of code in your @Bean definition above:

> sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations( **new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml")**
>   );
>
> Note: the method name is getResource**s** (the plural) and not getResource

Feel free to replace the hard coded value of `classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml` with the `@Value("datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-location-pattern")` injected value instead.

Because you're using MyBatis with Spring, the issue here is not so much a MyBatis issue, as much as it is a Spring issue. More specifically, the wildcard feature that you want to use to load multiple resources, namely, `classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml` is specific to Spring and not MyBatis.

I know, that the way it's documented in the MyBatis-Spring docs may lead you to believe that it's a MyBatis feature that let's you do this type of wildcard Resource loading, but it's not. Here's the relevant part of the MyBatis-Spring doc (source: https://mybatis.org/spring/factorybean.html#properties):

> The mapperLocations property takes a list of resource locations. This property can be used to specify the location of MyBatis XML mapper files. **The value can contain Ant-style patterns to load all files in a directory or to recursively search all paths from a base location.**

However, sadly the docs only provide a Spring example based on XML and not Java configuration. If you read the Java Docs docs for `SqlSessionFactoryBean`, you'll find the following (source: https://mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/org/mybatis/spring/SqlSessionFactoryBean.html#setMapperLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource...)):

```
public void setMapperLocations(org.springframework.core.io.Resource... mapperLocations)

Set locations of MyBatis mapper files that are going to be merged into the
SqlSessionFactory configuration at runtime.

This is an alternative to specifying "<sqlmapper>" entries in an MyBatis config file.
This property being based on Spring's resource abstraction also allows for
specifying resource patterns here: e.g. "classpath*:sqlmap/*-mapper.xml".

Parameters:
    mapperLocations - location of MyBatis mapper files
```

So, the `setMapperLocations` method needs one or more `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` object(s). So, using Spring `ClassPathResource` will not work here because `ClassPathResource` expects only a single resource. What you need to use instead is Spring's `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` class. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

You may also find this Stack Overflow post useful: [How to use wildcards when searching for resources in Java-based Spring configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250716/how-to-use-wildcards-when-searching-for-resources-in-java-based-spring-configura)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this long answer. The code snippet basically is my work around with the limitation that it doesn't support multiple patterns separated by ",". However, you make me believe that the work around is actually the intended way to solve the matter as the separation between Spring and MyBatis has to be kept in mind here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another method in your `MybatisConfig` class whose return type is `MapperScannerConfigurer`, it will help to set the `<mapper>` tag from `mybatisConfig.xml`.

```java
@Bean
public MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer(){
    MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
    mapperScannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("packagePath");
    return mapperScannerConfigurer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your property should be like this.
if you use default configuration,

```
mybatis.mapper-locations: classpath*:sqlmap/**/*.xml
```

if you use your own as you mention above,

```
datasource.mybatis-factory.mapper-locations= classpath*:sqlmap/**/*.xml
```

Comment: You haven't read my question (or maybe just parts of it). Your answer only adds subdirectories to the property, but nothing to solve the actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

this is a working example code, you can get an idea from this.

```java
@Configuration
@MapperScans(
        {

                @MapperScan(
                        basePackages = {"com.example.seeker.repository"},
                        sqlSessionFactoryRef = "sqlSessionFactorySeeker",
                        sqlSessionTemplateRef = "sqlSessionTemplateSeeker"
                )
        }
)
public class SeekerDataSourceConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean(value = "dsSeeker")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.seeker")
    DataSource dsSeeker() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Qualifier("dsSeeker")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dsSeeker;

    @Bean(value = "sqlSessionFactorySeeker")
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactorySeeker() {
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
            PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathM3R = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
            bean.setMapperLocations(pathM3R.getResources("classpath*:sqlmap/**/*.xml"));
            bean.setDataSource(dsSeeker);
            sessionFactory = bean.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(value = "sqlSessionTemplateSeeker")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplateSeeker() {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactorySeeker());
    }

    @Bean(name = StaticResource.TxManager.TX_MANAGER_SEEKER)
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dsSeeker);
    }

}
```

property file

```
spring.datasource.seeker.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://*********
spring.datasource.seeker.username=seeker***
spring.datasource.seeker.password=ewfky4eyrmggxbw6**
spring.datasource.seeker.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Can you point me to the difference to my work around please? The way I see it the only difference is that mine splits the configuration value at commas to allow multiple arguments. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: do you have the subfolders under the ```sqlmap``` folder ? or just only XML files?

Comment: your folder should be located at the path of ```\src\main\resources\sqlmap```

Comment: While it's in the question let me rephrase it: the problem is not finding the XML-files, it's how to have MyBatis have them loaded automatically from the configuration without my work around. Which brings us back to my question: Can you point me to the difference to my work around please?

Comment: if you use ```mybatis-spring-boot-starter``` dependency,  all of the auto-configuration default values it contains. that's how mybatis does without your involvement. please read this doc https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

Answer (score -1):

if you want to using with `yml` file you can add in the following path your application.yml file

```
mybatis:
  mapperLocations: classpath:sql/*.xml
  config-location: classpath:config/mybatis.xml
```